# reviewers plugin jar - not recogonized by gerrit

Tags: git, plugins, gerrit

I copied the reviewers plugin binary from [here](https://gerritcodereview-plugins.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) to gerrit/plugins but it doesn't show up in the gerrit plugins page. Has anyone used it? Any pointers to get it working appreciated.

Comment: Have you restarted Gerrit?

Comment: @fracz Yes. I did restart gerrit

Comment: Are the reviewers plugin and gerrit using the same version. For example, if gerrit is using 2.11 version, then reviewers has to be the same version.